Why will my python file run via a terminal command but not when I run the same command inside of a function in my Flutter macos app?
I want to execute python code in my Flutter macos app to run a YOLO object detection model.
I am using the https://pub.dev/packages?q=process_run package to execute shell commands.
The package works and will run a python file with a simple print function, but not my object detection file.
I have cloned https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5 inside of my app.
In my flutter app I have a function:
_runPython() async {
    var shell = Shell();

    await shell.run('''
    python3 yolov5/detect.py
    ''');
  }

When I call _runPython I get the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "yolov5/detect.py", line 39, in <module>
    import torch
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'

However when I run python3 yolov5/detect.py in my terminal the code executes just fine.
Looking inside of my python files inside of my app I don't see any errors, and everything appears to be imported.
Why is my detect.py working via the terminal and not from my Flutter app?

It could be, that shell used by var shell = Shell(); doesn't have same ENV variables that your terminal has (the one that you said it worked from), so pip's installed packages aren't in the PATH for that shell.
I think, process_run on MacOS uses "Default login shell" to run its commands from (/bin/zsh on my mac), but you may be using different shell in your terminal, that has pip's dependency installation location in its path. Try editing your default shell's configuration (~/.zshrc in my case) to have the same ENV variables and the same PATH as the shell that it works from has.
You can see your default and currently selected shells in Terminal app's settings (Screenshot from MacOS Ventura)
Before doing this, the simplest way to check would be to echo $PATH from both, your terminal and process_run's shells and compare.
P.S. I didn't replicate the issue, but I don't have enough StackOverflow reputation to post this as a comment to your post, thus I'm posting this as an answer. Hope this helps :)

Thanks for the comment.  Ultimately just creating a new project and reinstalling all the packages ended up fixing my issue.  I think there was a path issue like you mentioned, but I'm not sure exactly what the problem was...

running echo $PATH from shell.run only returned $PATH
